# What is wrong with my Assets class and AssetsManager? App not running

Tags: libgdx

I am not understanding why my application is causing problems whenever I try to run it. There are no errors although whenever I try to run the application it brings up the console with problems and the app wont run. I run "desktop".

Here is part of my **Assets** class ...

```
public class Assets implements Disposable {

public AssetManager manager;

public Assets (){
    init();
}

public void init () {

    manager = new AssetManager();

    manager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJ, TextureAtlas.class);

    manager.finishLoading();
}
```

Here is part of my **main** class ...

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener {

....

private Assets assets;

@Override
public void create() {      

...
    assets = new Assets();
...
}

@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    batch.begin();
    ...
    batch.end();
    }
```

When I try to run this, is gives me a problem like this in the **console**...

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: canyonbunny.pack (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
```

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: canyonbunny.pack (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:471)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:316)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:337)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.Assets.init(Assets.java:26)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.Assets.(Assets.java:17)
    at com.me.mygdxgame.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:32)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: canyonbunny.pack (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas$TextureAtlasData.(TextureAtlas.java:97)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureAtlasLoader.getDependencies(TextureAtlasLoader.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureAtlasLoader.getDependencies(TextureAtlasLoader.java:34)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleSyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:103)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:92)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:399)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:314)
    ... 6 more

I tried to locate the problem and I figured out when **i take the manager.finishedLoading() out**, my program runs. I even printed "Test" to the screen. But when I **leave the manager.finishedLoading() in**, it gives me console problems.

For further info, here is my **Constants** class ...

```
public class Constants {

public static final int WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
public static final int HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
public static final String TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJ =
        "canyonbunny.pack";
```

}

Comment: Have you successfully ran the app before or is this the first time you're running the app? On desktop that is. And are you using Eclipse?

Comment: If you are using Intellij make sure your running configuration has the correct assets folder, by default, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the inconvenience, I made a mistake with the Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJ -  I have misspelled "canyon bunny.pack" to "canyonbunny1.pack". I have made a typing error and this question is now closed!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer "Accepted" so the system knows it doesn't need to keep bumping the thread for more attention.